# What if there's current INTO an output pin?

Tags: current-source, level-translation, current-sink

maybe my question is easy to answer and maybe I shouldn't have asked it, but I'm really not sure.

I would like to connect an XBee ZigBee module (3.3 V) to a microcontroller (PIC, 5V) using the USARTs.
(I need to use 5 V. Using 3.3 V for the PIC is not an option.)

I want to use a level converter using two diodes as mentioned in Microchip's Tips'n Tricks document (DS01146B), page 8-7.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN3Okt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When building this circuit, I will happen that there's current flowing INTO the XBee's TX pin.
(This will be the case if the XBee wants to pull its Tx line to 0 V but there's some higher potential on the pin due to external parts.)

In the XBee's datasheet (document 90000866_A, page 8), there's some information on the maximum transmit current. It's 45 mA with Vcc = 3.3 V.
But "transmit current" suggests that it's outgoing current (or at least one could understand so).

Maybe the device is not capable of sinking current into the Tx pin as it's only designed to drive outgoing current?
Or maybe it accepts current into the chip, but not as much as outgoing current?

Can I be sure that the value for "Transmit current" refers to both current into and out from the device?

Comment: Transmit current refers to the current consumption of the device (current going into its Vcc terminal) while transmitting data over the air, and has nothing to do with its I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transmit current specification relates to how much power the entire module draws when the radio is transmitting, not the I/O pin drive capability.

I/O pins can generally source and sink current.  Sometimes you get I/O pins that can only sink current, these are called open drain or open collector outputs.  The pins used to drive I2C busses are open drain pins as they can only pull the bus low - it is pulled high with pull-up resistors.

As far as the XBee is concerned, it should be able to sink at least a few mA on its output I/O pins.  The datasheet lists the output drive voltages while sourcing or sinking 2 mA of current.  Doesn't look like they list a maximum value, interestingly.  Just make sure the pull up resistor is reasonably sized - try something between 1k and 10k ohms.